# Trying to get the id of XML when button is clicked and list the contents on another page PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm trying to get the ID from the the hotellist.php page. I'm not sure how to do it in XML since I'm new to it. Please explain.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $hotels) {          
        echo "<tr><td width='20%'><img src='".$hotels->image."'></td>"; 
        echo "<td width='60%'><h1>".$hotels->name."</h1><h3>"; 
        echo $hotels->address . "</h3></td>"; 
        echo "<td width='20%'><table id='price'><tr><td><h1>$".$hotels->price . "</h1></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td><a href=hotel.php?id=". $hotels->id ."><img src='image/btn_viewdetails.jpg'/></a></table></td></tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

And make the full contents appear in hotel.php

Here is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hotellist>
    <hotel>
        <id>1</id>
        <image>image/hotel/orchidgardenhotel.jpg</image>
        <name>Rizqun Hotel</name>
        <address>No. 15, Spg 447, Kg Kapok, Jalan Muara</address>
        <phone>8655425</phone>
        <price>60</price>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <id>2</id>
        <image>image/hotel/orchidgardenhotel.jpg</image>
        <name>Orchid Hotel</name>
        <address>No. 15, Spg 447, Kg Kapok, Jalan Muara</address>
        <phone>8655425</phone>
        <price>420</price>
    </hotel>
</hotellist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$hotels = $xml->xpath("//hotellist/hotel[id='{$id}']");
foreach($hotels as $hotel) {          
        echo $hotel->image . "\n"; 
        echo $hotel->name . "\n"; 
        echo $hotel->address . "\n"; 
        echo "$".$hotel->price . "\n";
        echo $hotel->id . "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I managed to send the ID to the url, for eg. hotel.php?id=1 but I'm not sure how to display the contents in hotel.php

Comment: Ok, so I have updated my answer to just add the id in xpath, it will get the info of particular node which has the provided id. Just assign `$id` variable

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for! Anyway, is there any tutorial for me to practice this? I've been googling about this and I can't seem to find any. I'm not sure if I've been googling wrong. Thanks in advance!